# How to view or convert .drv files?

Tags: conversion

Our office in downtown SF was robbed yesterday.  Some guy came into the building and walked into one of the offices and stole a laptop off someone's desk.  We have footage from the video cameras, but it's in a .drv format, which after doing some research were unable to find a player or a way to convert it to be played by VLC.  Does anyone know of such a file and how to view the contents?

Comment: What are the first dozen bytes in the .drv file? Those often contain a magic number.

Comment: Which camera? Have you tried contacting the manufacturer? Surely you must have considered possible playback methods if you installed something to record?

Comment: This site claims to have a .DRV player: http://preservesafetyandaccess.com/psa/surveillance.html

Comment: @Karan well, i'm unsure. the thief tried to get into another office too, which is were the footage came from.  i was just hoping i did not need to go that far or pay for some propriety program.

Comment: @slhck tried that already.. no luck :(

Comment: Ok, so maybe they (ought to) have some sort of system to play their own camera's footage back?

Comment: yeah they did.  my next step was to go down there and see what program etc.. try to contact the company.

Comment: 0000000 3240 0000 6300 0000 2c5b 5091 7982 5d01
0000010 0000 0074 7b1f 039d 0000 0000 0000 0001
0000020 0000 0000 006c 0000 6e45 7274 4879 6c61
0000030 006c 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000
0000040 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000
*
0000090 0000 0000 0000 e001 fa62 c187 3f17 872b
00000a0 310a 2b1f f285 0fbd 808b 608a cb80 0900
00000b0 ffff ffff 0000 0001 0000 2001 8800 987a
00000c0 b428 f020 1fa3 0000 b301 b26d 0067 0100 - so this is what i see, but i'm unsure where to go from here.